# Put ImageButton between two view groups

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `LinearLayout` with a `Toolbar` inside it and an `EditText` and a `Button`. I'm using images to express what i want, it is simple:

This is what I have right now: (the `ImageButton` with the logo is in the `Toolbar`)

[image]

And this is what I want to achieve: (The `ImageButton` with the logo is between the `Toolbar` and the `LinearLayout`)

[image]

This is my XML code for the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/secondColor"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mainColor"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="-10dp">


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMenu"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.ImageButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_principal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
                android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/spotify_logo" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>



<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/editReminderTitleHint"
    />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing your `LinearLayout` top-level view into a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:hint="Reminder title"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edit"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:text="BUTTON"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

The important part here is that you constrain **both** the top and bottom of the `ImageButton` to the bottom of the `Toolbar`. This will center it on the bottom edge of the toolbar.

[image]

Note that I didn't set a special background for my example ImageButton, but you can make it a circle and it will work just fine.